# How to swap the call in Android?

Tags: android, call

How to swap the calls in android programmatically means I have a call already in progress I am receiving the second call and connected. Now I want to swap to the first call should be the active call. How can I achieve that via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the phone app can directly control calls. There is no public API in the framework for a 3rd party app to switch or otherwise control the phone state.